# While writing query for bigQuery how to write table name and column name using variables instead of hard coding

Tags: google-bigquery, python-bigquery

In the below mentioned query projectname-dataset-tableName is hardcoded in the query

```
query = """
SELECT city from bigquery-public-data.openaq.global_air_quality WHERE country = 'IN'
"""
```

How to write the same in more dynamic way? The fulltableid attribute is not returning compatible format.

```
query1 = """
SELECT city from """ + str(tableGAQ.full_table_id) + """ WHERE country = 'IN'
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had the following query:

```
query = (
"SELECT name FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` "
'WHERE state = "TX" '
"LIMIT 100"
)
```

To use a variable to dynamically introduce your table ID, your query will look like this:

```
tableID = "`bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`"
query = (
"SELECT name FROM"+ tableID + "
'WHERE state = "TX" '
"LIMIT 100"
```

)

Notice that your table name has to be written between ` `.